# Reduccion o resumen codigo vba

Tags: excel, vba, optimización

Este fragmento de codigo tiene dos secciones pero estoy seguro de que se puede reducir a una, ¿Alguien sabria como hacerlo? Gracias de antemano

```
 pos = 3
    While Cells(pos, 4) <> vbNullString
        lista2 = lista2 & Replace(Cells(pos, 4), ",", " ") & ","
        pos = pos + 1
Wend

lista3 = vbNullString

pos = 3
While Cells(pos, 6) <> vbNullString
    lista3 = lista3 & Replace(Cells(pos, 6), ",", " ") & ","
    pos = pos + 1
Wend

lista4 = "vbNullString"

pos = 3
While Cells(pos, 8) <> vbNullString
    lista4 = lista4 & Replace(Cells(pos, 8), ",", " ") & ","
    pos = pos + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Podrías definir un rango desde la fila 1 hasta la primera fila con datos vacíos, recorrerlo y validar el contenido en la columna 4 y 6 para hacer lo que necesitas hacer. De paso te ahorras el contador.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco demasiado de VBA, pero creo que una estructura podría acercarse a lo de más abajo..

Espero que te ayude, un saludo!

```
Dim Pos4EsBlanco = false
Dim Pos6EsBlanco = false

While !Pos4EsBlanco Or !Pos6EsBlanco
    Pos4EsBlanco = Cells(pos, 4) == ""
    Pos6EsBlanco = Cells(pos, 6) == ""

    If !Pos4EsBlanco Then
        lista2 = lista2 & Replace(Cells(pos, 4), ",", " ") & ","
    End If
    If pos >= 3 And !Pos6EsBlanco Then
        lista3 = lista3 & Replace(Cells(pos, 6), ",", " ") & ","
    End If

    pos = pos + 1
Wend
```